# Ways to shrink a snapshot?

Tags: digital-ocean

Given that Digital Ocean is now going to start charging for snapshots by the GB, are there any tips or techniques to minimizing the size of a snapshot?

I have one snapshot of an system I use for periodic development and testing of some web apps that has ballooned to 2GB, while some others are only a few hundred megs.

I'm assuming if you're starting from scratch, things like avoiding updates and creating new files/editing many OS files might be good. Anything else?

Comment: Might this be better asked on http://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: Given that there's a Digital-Ocean tag here, but not one on SuperUser, I posted here, but I guess I'll also ask over there.